# Centroid and midpoints cyclic then prove that $AC^2 + BC^2 = 2AB^2.$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABC$ be a non-equilateral triangle with integer sides. Let $D$ and $E$ be respectively the mid-points of $BC$ and $CA$ ; let $G$ be the centroid of $\Delta{ABC}$. Suppose, $D$, $C$, $E$, $G$ are concyclic.Prove that  $AC^2 + BC^2 = 2AB^2.$

My progress:

[image]

- By angle chase we get, $$\angle GBA=\angle GED=\angle GCD\implies (CGB)~~\text{is tangent to}~~AB.$$
- Similarly, we get $$\angle GAB=\angle GDE=\angle GCE\implies (CGA)~~\text{is tangent to}~~AB.$$
- By power of point, we have $$\frac{AB^2}{4}=FA^2=FB^2=FG\cdot FC=\frac{1}{3}FG^2. $$

Comment: That's nice working! You just missed the simple part :)

Comment: @MathLover yeah I actually didn't know about the formula..Learnt something new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly done:

$$
\frac{AB^2}{4}=\frac{1}{3}FC^2 \tag{1}
$$

From Appolonius' Theorem:

$$b^2 + a^2=2 FC^2 + \frac{c^2}{2}$$

$$\implies FC^2=\frac{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}{4}$$

Substituting for $FC^2$ in $Eq(1)$:

$$\frac{c^2}{4}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}{4}$$

A little algebra yields the answer.

Answer (score 2):

From your working, $ \displaystyle \frac{AB^2}{4}=FA^2=FB^2=FG\cdot FC=\frac{1}{3}FC^2$

Now to finish off, you can use the formula of median in terms of side lengths.

$FC^2 = \cfrac{1}{4} (2 AC^2 + 2 BC^2 - AB^2)$

So, $\cfrac{AB^2}{4} = \cfrac{1}{12} (2 AC^2 + 2 BC^2 - AB^2)$

$ \implies 2 AB^2 = AC^2 + BC^2$